# Data Factory: How to pass JSON as text to Web Body

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have to pass multiple records from a SQL source to the body of a web call in Data Factory in JSON format.

eg.

```
{"EmployeeCode":"1234",""FirstName":"Joe","LastName":"Bloggs"}
{"EmployeeCode":"5678",""FirstName":"Jack","LastName":"Ryan"}
```

However, I cannot seem to do it without ADF adding escape characters "\".

```
{\\"EmployeeCode\\":\\"1234\\",\\"\\"FirstName\\":\\"Joe\\",\\"LastName\\":\\"Bloggs\\"}"
```

So far I have tried:

1. Copy activity - Formatted SQL as JSON
2. Copy activity - SQL output to BLOB JSON
3. Copy activity - SQL concatenated string output

Does anyone have a process by which to achieve this?  I am hoping I have missed something easy.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: You might try putting `@json('<your JSON here>')` around the JSON string for a single line and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Escape character backslash `\` appears wherever double quotes `"` are used in the string in the Azure data factory.

Thank you @GregGalloway for your valuable input in the comments sections. As @GregGalloway mentioned, convert the string to **JSON** format in the web body as shown in the below example.

**Example**:

1. Source: SQL data

[image]

2. Getting SQL records using lookup activity.

[image]

3. Passing the output record to web activity in JSON format.

`@json(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].description)`

[image]

The input of the web activity body is shown as below in JSON format:

[image]